# How add subview to UIView in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiview

How add subview to UIView in Swift 4? Need work in Swift 3 and Swift 4 (iOS 10+)

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewBody: UIView!
@objc var loadIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
@objc let loadBody = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))

@objc func activityLoad() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async() {

        self.loadIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
        self.loadBody.removeFromSuperview()

        self.loadBody.frame = CGRect(x: self.viewBody.frame.midX - 23, y: self.viewBody.frame.midY - 23, width: 46, height: 46)
        self.loadBody.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.loadBody.alpha = 1//0.7
        self.loadBody.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.loadIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
        self.loadIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 46)
        self.loadIndicator.startAnimating()

        self.loadBody.addSubview(self.loadIndicator)
        self.viewBody.addSubview(self.loadBody)

    }

}
```

Error: **Do not add subviews directly to the visual effect view itself, instead add them to the -contentView.'**

if i add self.viewBody.contentView.addSubview(self.loadBody)

Error: **Value of type UIView has no member contentView.**

I need your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems like the compiler thinks that `viewBody` is an instance of `UIVisualEffectView`. Try cleaning the project.

Comment: viewBody frame ?

Comment: show declaration for `loadBody`

Comment: @objc let loadBody = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))

Comment: I don't think your code snippet shows the correct error location. Do you somewhere add further views to the `loadBody` view?

Comment: no, only here...

Comment: paste please all your code here

Comment: pasted all code

Comment: UIVisualEffectView has a `contentView` property, and you should add subview to this `contentView`. So just change your code to `self.loadBody.contentView.addSubview(self.loadIndicator)`.

Comment: big thanks you! This is true!

Answer (score 2):

UIVisualEffectView has a contentView property, and you should add subview to this contentView. So just change your code to self.loadBody.contentView.addSubview(self.loadIndicator). – mrfour 20 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

Apple says that;

> Depending on the desired effect, the effect may affect content layered
>   behind the view or content added to the visual effect view’s
>   contentView. Apply a visual effect view to an existing view and then
>   apply a UIBlurEffect or UIVibrancyEffect object to apply a blur or
>   vibrancy effect to the existing view. After you add the visual effect
>   view to the view hierarchy, add any subviews to the contentView
>   property of the visual effect view. **Do not add subviews directly to
>   the visual effect view itself**.

**Add your subviews to content view of visual effect view**

```
 self.loadBody.contentView.addSubview(self.loadIndicator)
```